# Content body causing space between navbar and header HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm making a simple web page for practice and attempting to incorporate an image gallery, but I think I messed up my divs somehow because when I add content to the main part like image thumbnails they cause a weird gap between the header and left navbar. It's probably some simple solution but I'm super beginner so it's escaping me. Any help at all is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">  
    <title>Lab 8</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      
</head>
<body>
        <img class= "image" alt="flower" src="flower.jpg"style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
        
            <h1 class="header">Photos By Doug</h1>

       <div id ="wrapper">
        <main> Here is some content info about Doug Kowalski Photography
          <img src="desert.jpg" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="100" />
          <img src="hills.jpg" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="100"/>  
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#">Home</a><br>
            <a href="#">Journals</a><br>
            <a href="#">Books</a><br>
            <a href="#">Nature</a><br>
            <a href="#">Contact</a><br>
          </div>
              
          <img class ="image2" alt="vine" src="vine.jpg"style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
       
        </main>

</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #88abc2;
    margin:0;
  }

  .image{
      height: 250px;
      border-radius:5px; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-bottom:10px;
      float:left;
      width: 25%
  }

  .header{
      display:flex;
      padding-top: 100px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: papyrus;
      background-color:#49708A;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items:center;
  }

#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:67%;
}

.nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color:#49708A;
  } 

.nav a{
    padding-left:3px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EBF7F8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.nav a:hover {
    color: #CAFF42;
  }


main{
   padding-top: 38px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 30%;
}

.image2{
    height:10%;
    width:15%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 0px; 
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    left:-35px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Edit: and a photo of the area in question:
[image]

Comment: make a sccreenshot and circle out where exactly is the gap that you want to remove

Comment: good suggestion. edited it in

Comment: You have to fix your HTML structure and add few CSS, then it should be OK - here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/tester2020/pen/QWvbqQG?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?
I saw this:

```html
<div id=wrapper>
 <main>
</div>
</main>
```

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Edit: Mistyped styles.css
[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: I get what you're saying, but when I remove that </div> after <main> my navbar becomes really skinny and is near the center of the page. Should it be outside the wrapper ?

Comment: @Galaxyxo U should put the main content [in the main-tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).